# Node.js - res.sendFile - Error: ENOENT but the path is correct

Tags: node.js, express, sendfile

I'm trying to render an index.html but I get the error enoent, even with the right path.

```
//folders tree
test/server.js
test/app/routes.js
test/public/views/index.html

//routes.js    
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('views/index.html');
});


//server.js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
require('./app/routes')(app);
```

I also tried

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
```

If I use

```
res.sendfile('./public/views/index.html');
```

then it works, but I see a warning that says sendfile is deprecated and I have to use sendFile.

Comment: What happens when you `console.log` the path that you're putting into `sendFile`? Do you get the path you expect?

Comment: It gives me the path '/Users/me/Desktop/test/app/public/views/index.html' and it is supposed to be the correct path

Comment: Could you include the **complete** error message then? It seems odd that    the path is correct yet it still doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried `res.sendFile('/views/index.html');` ?

Comment: with res.sendFile('/views/index.html'); I get
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/views/index.html'
   at Error (native)

Comment: actually if you're just serving static files the expected thing is to not have the route defined at all, thats what the static middleware does.

Comment: the complete error is: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/me/Desktop/test/app/views/index.html'
   at Error (native)

Comment: and is there a file at this path?

Comment: Just to be sure are you trying to render the html page for viewing in a browser or are you actually trying to send a file for download ? If you just want to render you need res.render() not res.sendFile()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding :

```
 var path = require('path');
 var filePath = "./public/views/index.html"
 var resolvedPath = path.resolve(filePath);
 console.log(resolvedPath);
 return res.sendFile(resolvedPath);
```

This should clear up whether the file path is what you expect it to be

Comment: This one worked, I see now that the path was not correct, it was seeking the folder views in the folder app instead of the folder public. Thanks to everybody for the help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the root option, that did it for me :

```
var options = {
    root: __dirname + '/public/views/',
};

res.sendFile('index.html', options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(err.status).end();
    }
    else {
      console.log('Sent:', fileName);
    }
  });
```

Comment: { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/me/Desktop/test/app/public/views/index.html'
    at Error (native)
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/Users/me/Desktop/test/app/public/views/index.html',
  expose: false,
  statusCode: 404,
  status: 404 }

Comment: is there a file there?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've defined static file middleware, but then you define a route in front of that that tries to handle serving the static files (so the static file middleware actually does nothing here). So if you want to `res.sendFile` something from a route you would need to give either an absolute path to it. Or, you could just remove the `app.get('*', ...)` route and let the express middleware do its job.

Comment: `res.sendFile` always takes an absolute path, according to the API docs: "Unless the root option is set in the options object, path must be an absolute path to the file."

Comment: OK I'll correct the answer, but my main point was that there's no need to `res.sendFile` in the first place. The route should be removed so that the middleware defined can do its job.

Comment: yup, agreed on that

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/views')));
```

Handle api call

```
app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('req is -> %s', req.url);
    if (req.url == '/dashboard') {
        console.log('redirecting to  -> %s', req.url);
        res.render('dashboard');
    } else {
        res.render('index');
    }

});
```